# main.c|4|error C2059: syntax error : 'type'| i dont know y=why this error is popping up

Tags: c

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int max(int num1, int num2) {
    int result;
    if(num1 > num2) {
        result =num1;
    } else {
        result = num2;
    }
    return result;
}

int main() {
    printf("%d",max(4,3));
    return 0;
}
```

I do not understand why this is not working; it is telling me:

> main.c|4|error C2059: syntax error : 'type'|

I do not know why this error is popping up.

Comment: Can you copy/paste the actual, indended code giving the error?

Comment: What are the `###` doing in your code? You might as wel use `MIN`/`MAX` from `sys/param.h` or you should at least prefix your own function names to prevent clashing with your platform. Which platform are we talking about anyway? Could you rename your `max` function to `my_max` and see if that works? Besides the `###` this code seems not so wrong.

Comment: @Cheatah I neglected to remove that `###` when I code-formatted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear that one of the library header files (most likely `stdlib.h`) is providing a macro definition for `max`, and this is conflicting with your own function definition.

To resolve this, either rename your function (say `mymax`) or add the following line after the two `#include` lines:

```c
#undef max
```

Or, if you want to  be more thorough:

```c
#ifdef max
#undef max
#endif
```

Another option, as you aren't actually using anything from the `stdlib.h` header, is just to remove (or comment out) the `#include <stdlib.h>` line (but that may affect code you later add to your program).

NOTE: Compilers (such as `MSVC`) that give macro definitions for `max` and `min` are, strictly speaking, not conforming to the C Language Standard. However, that doesn't seem to prevent their implementers from doing it. If you *are* using `MSVC`, then you can also prevent this error by including the following line *immediately* before including the `stdlib.h` header:

```c
#undef _CRT_INTERNAL_NONSTDC_NAMES
#include <stdlib.h>
```

You can also fix the problem *without* changing your code, by adding the `/Za` complier option (or set "Disable Language Extensions" to "Yes" in the project's C/C++ properties).

Comment: That would make the compiler lib non-compliant, so I find the explanation unlikely.

Comment: @Lundin Well, MSVC certainly has that definition in `stdlib.h`, but it *is* in a conditional block guarded by `#if defined(_CRT_INTERNAL_NONSTDC_NAMES) && _CRT_INTERNAL_NONSTDC_NAMES` (with a comment: *"Non-ANSI Names for Compatibility"*).

Comment: And their libs are also quite non-compliant, so... We have to assume that the OP is using standard C unless told otherwise.

Comment: @Lunding I just copied the OP's code and tried to build it (in MSVC). I got this: **error C2059: syntax error: '<parameter-list>'**. So I'm fairly confident that my diagnosis is correct.

Comment: Ok because it compiles cleanly if you try a standard C compiler, including Mingw that uses the Microsoft libs. So this should be re-tagged Visual Studio or some such perhaps, but the OP could tell us what "supposed C" compiler they are using.

Comment: @AhmadhishamAfify In your case, the 'macro' in `stdlib.h` is this: `#define max(a,b) (((a) > (b)) ? (a) : (b))`. For more info on macros in general, see [this tutorial](https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/cpreprocessor.html).